# Magento 2 stop clearing cart if user switch between Websites

Tags: magento, cart

I'm working on a Magento 2.4.2 with different websites. If a user add some items on a Web Site, open a new tab on the same browser and then visites another Web Site, the cart get emptied.

How can I stop Magento from doing that?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/sharing-sessions-between-stores-with-different-domains may help you?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

assuming a single domain, you have multiple websites created in Admin -> Stores -> Settings -> All Stores

Make sure that in Stores -> Configuration -> Customers ->
Customer Configuration -> Account Sharing Options section.
Set the “Share Customer Accounts” setting to “Global”